# scandir not rendering properly

Tags: php, html

Here is the code relevent to the question. Basically, the problem is, on the root of my website, it is displaying the folder "Test" properly, but once you follow the link into "test" it no longer displays test.

```
$src = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
foreach ($src as $path){
    if (is_dir($path)){
        if ($path !== 'stats' and $path !== 'data' and $path !== '..' and $path !== '.'){
        echo "<li><a href='/$path'>$path</a></li>";
        }
    }
}
```

here is a `print_r` of `$src`

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => Test
    [3] => background.png
    [4] => content_back.png
    [5] => data
    [6] => footer.png
    [7] => header.png
    [8] => index.php
    [9] => main.html
    [10] => stats
    [11] => style.css
)
```

Comment: what's in your $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] before and after clicking on "test"?

Comment: why should it? You're just fetching subdirs, but doing nothing to fetch information about parent dirs.

Comment: Everything is being scanned from the document root, which is www.codebundle.net/ so I assumed that they would be rendered the same way, as the directory being scanned has not change. The debug code seen on the site shows what is in the scandir of document root on both pages, relevant to both pages. As you can see it is the same.

Comment: I see no change what so ever if I click on test, what is the problem or have you solved it allready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use absolute path for is_dir:

```
if (is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $path)){
```

Comment: To clarify for Pitchinnate: once you follow the link, scandir is looking for the contents grabbed from DOCUMENT_ROOT in your new folder (DOCUMENT_ROOT/Test), not in DOCUMENT_ROOT.  You're using relative references.

Comment: if (is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path)){
Now in use. No change made to main page. Changing back

Comment: and I just realised that would make my code relative anyway, so I can see what he was trying, but not the desired effect. Thanks for the help anyway, but as this is not the solution I was looking for, I am not going to mark as an answer.

Comment: do you think you could remove this in a bit if no actual answer is found, as this is not the answer I am looking for, and people are less likely to view this as they see it has an answer.

Comment: You want it to list the directories on root no matter what or you want it relative to the page you are on?

Comment: yeah, which is what the original code should be for. However it isn't doing that for some reason

Comment: You didn't answer the question, relative to page or only root directories?

Comment: only list the directories inside the root directory (and not the ones I have added !== to ignore obviously)

Comment: Try it again, and make sure you clear your browser cache (hit ctrl-F5 a few times).  This is the correct answer.

Comment: I've already edited that in and fixed it, now can you explain why it works? I'm looking at it, and thinking that shouldn't it now be working relative to the $path, or am I just getting horribly confused? Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Your horribly confused. You are scanning the root directory. But that doesn't change the fact that `is_dir()` is based off the directory the php page you are running is located. That is why you need to use an absolute path to the directory you are checking. Otherwise it is looking for /Test/Test which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized, thank you, I must just be tired today, I don't normally make mistakes that bad :/